# Rationale behind non existent of the expectation

Tags: expected-value, integral

[image]

In this problem, I know that the expectation does not exist because the integral will involve terms of log which goes to infinity as x(it's argument) goes to infinity. Hence, the expectation does not exist. Am I thinking right, if not please put light on when expectation does not exist. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add `[self-study]` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Hint: The correct answer is none of those proposed.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me Stephan. I want to know how can I type the mathematical expressions using my smartphone?

Comment: This page https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help right at the bottom gives some very, very brief hints.